# Javascript html5 how to convert binary data into string

Tags: javascript, html

```
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var rawData = new ArrayBuffer();            
    //console.log(1);

    reader.onload = function(e) {


        var rawData = e.target.result; //binary data
        console.log(rawData);


    }
```

I want to see explicitly the binary raw data as a text string, is that possible?, cause the only thing i see when logging is:

```
ArrayBuffer {}
```

Comment: so the rawData is in the form 1,0,1,1,0,1? and you want it like 101101?

Comment: @AbdulJabbar anyhow just to print it and see it explicitly

Comment: I think you need to use one of the FileReader methods to read the data first. http://devdocs.io/dom/filereader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
console.log(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(rawData)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what'I've needed:

```
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

then the data is available raw